# npm EACCES error again after fixing it

Tags: npm, npm-install, express-generator

I was having an issue where I couldn't use npm to install things globally and I fixed it by following the instructions here and making a .npm-global directory. My computer restarted and updated software and now it doesn't work again and I redid the instructions but its not helping. Any idea what could be happening?

```
$ npm install -g express-generator
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied,
```

Comment: you need to use `sudo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tip at the bottom is actually more useful.

"If you are using npm version 5.2 or greater, explore npx as an alternative way to run global commands, especially if you just need a command occassionally. Click here to read an excellent article about npx."

npx works great. 
https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Answer (score 1):

After following the instructions here like I said https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions it worked for a bit but then stopped working. What fixed it was resetting my prefix.

`npm config set prefix ~/.npm-globall`